# php removing numbers from a string and a letter if it's there

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm looking at a way of removing a property number from an address.

For example the address could be - 56 Hello Road

I've managed to use the following code to remove the number and that works

```
            $meta_url = trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'', $row[property_address_1]));
```

However if the address is 56b Hello Road it leaves the b and returns - b Hello Road

Any idea how I can edit my current code to remove the next corresponding letter?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a [regular expression](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]+[a-z]/', '', $row['property_address_1'])
```

The expression means:

- `[0-9]+` one or more characters in the range 0-9, followed by
- `[a-z]` one lowercase character in the range a-z

Answer (score 0):

First you may want to split your string at spaces, then look at the first item if it fits a certain condition:

```
<?php 

    $addressParts = explode(" ",$property_address);
    if(preg_match('/\b[0-9]+[a-z]{0,2}\b/', $addressParts[0], $matches)){
        unset($addressParts[0]);
    }
    $property_address = implode(" ",$addressParts);

?>
```

`/\b[0-9]+[a-z]{0,2}\b/` means:

`\b`: word boundary at start

`[0-9]+` : any length of numeric chars

`[a-z]{0,2}` : min 0 max 2 chars of alphanumeric chars

`\b`: word boundary at end